# My Popup window is not closing when the button is pressed twice in android

Tags: android, popupwindow

Hi all i am trying to put custom popup in layout popup is showing properly. If the button in pressed once and you click dismiss or outside area it is closing properly  but when the button is pressed twice the popup is not all closing. Can anybody suggest on my below code.

```
                 popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.word_meaning, null, false);      
                    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                           popupView, 
                           100,  
                                 100, true);
                dismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                // Removes default black background
                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                dismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) { System.out.println("dismiss");
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        //System.out.println("View"+popupView.getVisibility());
                    }});
                popupView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rel_layout.addView(popupView);
```

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with it but why are you setting the `visibility` to `gone`? When you `dismiss()` the `PopupWindow` it should remove the `View` anyway.

Comment: @codeMagic it seems to be not happening in my code... any idea

Comment: I meant what happens if you take that line out? `popupView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: @codeMagic if that is out View is not gone

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to use the back button that is native to the device you want to put the closing action in a onBackPressed() method in the activity. ie

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    //code
}
```